# How do I know if my EJB bean is started/running on JBOSS AS 7

Tags: java, jboss, jboss7.x, ear

I've made some changes to the standalone.xml file so that our EJB file that worked fine under JBoss 6 will maybe work on 7.  I've checked the log file and I see failed processes but nothing that relates to my EAR file, I think.  I see in the log file that my file is found and a message that a dodeploy file should be created.  Does this mean that the ear file was successfully started or not?  I don't see any error or fail message after that.

Comment: By default JBoss 7 logs which EJBs are deployed I believe, so if you don't see any of that I have bad news for you. But likely you simply didn't tell JBoss to deploy the application to begin with which is what that message is referring to. You need to create a trigger file before JBoss actually deploys it.

Comment: @Gimby thank you.  I am new to this world.  How do I create a dodeploy file?  I'll look it up...

Comment: Good that you say you'll look it up, documentation is your friend ;) I think there are at least 5 different ways to deploy an application in JBoss 7. If this is in a development environment, Eclipse + the JBoss Tools plugins is by far the easiest.

Comment: @Gimby so after looking it up, skipping the parts about using consoles, since I do not have access to the server, only the admin, it doesn't make sense.  Should I create an empty file with the same name as my ear file?  Is that all there is to it?  My ear file is dodsr.ear so I should create an empty file called dodsr.ear.dodeploy?